# Question about a theorem of Goodwillie on periodic cyclic homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cyclic-homology

In his paper Cyclic homology, Derivations and the Free Loopsace, Goodwillie defines periodic cyclic homology for differential graded algebras (A,d) concentrated in non-negative degree. 
Why does he make this restriction?

Elsewhere, for example in Jones' work on the same topic, periodic cyclic homology is defined for arbitrary dga's. Suppose that we have a dg-algebra which is co-connective, e.g. $A_n=0$ for $n>0$.

Is it true that $\operatorname{HP}_*((A,d)) \cong \operatorname{HP}_*(H_0(A))$ ?

Comment: No, this is not true. You can probably see this in any non-trivial example...

Comment: I would like to guess that this is due to the fact that for all ring spectra $A$, both Postnikov sections $A\to\pi_0 A$ and surjections of discrete rings with nilpotent kernels are compositions of square-zero extensions. For the former being "square-zero", I would like to refer to Lurie's [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf) Definition 7.4.1.18 of $n$-small extensions.